# On Error Cleanup Mechanism in TCL

Tags: tcl

Mechanism to call appropriate function if error occurred in function itself.

```
proc abc {} {

    ;# Overhere is it possible to get some mechanism that is used to
    ;# check if error occurs calls appropriate function

    if {something} {
        error "" "" 0
    }
    if {something} {
        error "" "" -1
    }
    if {something} {
        error "" "" 255
    }
}

;# Clean up function
proc cleanup {} {
}
```

Tried `exit` instead of `error`, but i was not able to catch that exit inside signal function of `TclX` like,

```
set l1 "INT TERM EXIT HUP"
signal trap $l1 cleanup
```

Error is like, You can't use Exit as argument to signal.

One thing i know is that, i can catch that error at the time of function calling. like,

```
set retval [catch {abc}]
```

But can i have some mechanism inside function itself kind of interrupt handler as given in comment of first part of code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Tcl 8.6, the simplest mechanism is this:

```
proc abc {} {
    try {
        if {something} {
            error "" "" 0
        }
        if {something} {
            error "" "" -1
        }
        if {something} {
            error "" "" 255
        }
    } finally {
        cleanup
    }
}
```

Otherwise (8.5 or before), you can use an unset trace on an otherwise-unused local variable to fire the cleanup code:

```
proc abc {} {
    set _otherwise_unused "ignore this value"
    # This uses a hack to make the callback ignore the trace arguments
    trace add variable _otherwise_unused unset "cleanup; #"

    if {something} {
        error "" "" 0
    }
    if {something} {
        error "" "" -1
    }
    if {something} {
        error "" "" 255
    }
}
```

If you're using 8.6, you should use `try … finally …` for this as you've got cleaner access to the local variables of `abc`; unset traces can run at relatively difficult times.

Comment: You can also simulate `try` with `catch` and `return`, but it is annoying to write the code.

Comment: i have also another lots of code between multiple "if", above "if" and below "if" that i mentioned inside question. so i can't use first solution to put whole code inside try and finally... i will try second one... which is kind new to me...

Comment: Can u please elaborate more on second.. what it is doing ? if possible

Comment: Unset traces are callbacks that run when a variable is unset; if you're not using `unset` explicitly, that happens when their scope (a local stack frame or a namespace) is destroyed. Thus, setting an unset trace on a _local_ variable that you then leave completely alone is a good way to get a callback when the local stack frame is destroyed. (I expect it to change in Tcl 9.0 — local var traces are too expensive — but this death-of-frame callback behaviour is too useful so there'll be some other mechanism.)